# vagrant how to access web server (nginx) with public ip

Tags: nginx, vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I have tried doing it like this in my vagrantfile

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip : "192.168.33.15"
```

so when I start my box, I could access nginx through my browser 'locally'.
what I want is to access it using public ip. I have tried this, (found in documentation)

```
config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "202.137.x.x", netmask: "255.255.x.x"

config.vm.provision "shell",
run: "always",
inline: "route add default gw 202.137.x.x"


config.vm.provision "shell",
run: "always",
inline: "eval `route -n | awk '{ if ($8 ==\"eth0\" && $2 != \"0.0.0.0\") print \"route del default gw \" $2; }'`"
```

this still doesn't work. any ideas?

*edit 
I've also tried port forwarding,

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, host_ip: "202.137.x.x"
```

I have to do this: 202.137.x.x:8080, I wanted to access without the port. 
 Also, host port cannot be < 1024, so I cannot put port 80..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried doing port forwarding in windows (host), so this is how I solved it..

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=80 listenaddress=202.137.x.x connectport=8080 connectaddress=202.137.x.x
```

This forwards any requests to the host on port 80 to port 8080 on the host. 
So, the port forwarding flow becomes: 
**host:80 => host:8080 => guest:80**

[source here](https://davidsimpson.me/2014/01/08/port-forwarding-for-host-machine-to-vagrant-guest-web-server/)